# Powershell: Find running process, if process is running abort the script, if not then continue with the script

Tags: sccm

Looking to update Putty on 100+ PCs using SCCM.

Putty isn't very good at overwriting so I've created a Powershell script to remove any older versions and then install the new one.

I'd like to add a line or two at the start to check if the user is already has Putty open.  If putty is open, the script should cancel/abort.  If it's not running the script should continue and uninstall the old version and install the new.

Any ideas?

Comment: the check is really not hard (get-process <processname> -erroraction silentlycontinue).count -gt 0 but with sccm you would have to think about what happens then. if you abort all scripts where an update is not possible how do you plan on upgrading the rest? do you want to use a program or an application in sccm?

Comment: Obviously, I meant abort the script on that machine that happens to have Putty running...

The script is deployed to all the machines local caches, and the script runs from there.  The script works, but would be nice to have a 'is the process running and abort if it is' to not interrupt people who may be working on Putty.

Comment: That code in an if around the installer is enough to abort but the thing is more what to do with the machines where you aborted. How to guarantee that at the end all are updated? You can do what austen suggested but it will lead to (minor) errors reported on sccm when someone does not close for more than 6 hours. you can also prompt the user and give him a choice for 5 hours then force. You can fail and rerun n times. You can use an application that reruns until it works once. Depending on how you prefer to handle the failures a different solution is imo the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Credit to Austen Ewald.

This will exit the script if the process (Putty) is running and remove old and install the new if its not.  I will simply "monitor" the results in a SCCM collection looking for versions of Putty older than 0.73.

```
Do {
        $status = Get-Process "putty*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If (($status)) { Write-Host 'Waiting for process to close...' ; exit }
        Else { Write-Host 'Process has closed' ; $closed = $true }
    }
 Until ( $closed )

$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Putty*" } | select UninstallString
$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Putty*" } | select UninstallString
if ($uninstall64) {
$uninstall64 = $uninstall64.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
$uninstall64 = $uninstall64.Trim()
Write "Uninstalling..."
start-process msiexec.exe -arg "/X $uninstall64 /quiet /norestart" -Wait}
if ($uninstall32) {
$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()
Write "Uninstalling..."
start-process msiexec.exe -arg "/X $uninstall32 /quiet /norestart" -Wait}
    Start-Sleep -s 10
msiexec.exe /i .\putty-64bit-0.73-installer.msi /quiet /norestart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PSAppDeployToolkit](https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/) to achieve this. Depending on how you want to deploy it to your users. You can easily configure this to wait for the program to close, close it automatically or prompt the user to close the process.

Alternatively, If you just want your script to wait until Putty is closed you could just use a simple loop to wait for the process to close.

```
 Do {
        $status = Get-Process "putty" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If (($status)) { Write-Host 'Waiting for process to close...' ; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 }
        Else { Write-Host 'Process has closed' ; $closed = $true }
    }
 Until ( $closed )
```

Comment: I had this working first attempt, but now it seems to closing putty and continuing (or continuing to the next staqe which is to uninstall which then closes Putty. I'll post my full script below...

Comment: @TomJ123 Looking at your Script. When you're Looking for the process it doesn't go by the name in Task Manager, so SSH* will not work. If it is putty the process name is actually putty. 
`PS C:\> Get-Process "Putty"

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    204      13     2620      11888       0.13  17172  17 putty
`

Comment: Sorry I did have "Putty" in there too but I was trying other methods. Same result.